# Weird active connections in NetStat

Tags: php, laravel, windows, command, netstat

I recently ran netstat on my system and noticed some connections from an old Laravel project that I had previously deleted. Despite removing the project entirely, these connections are still present:

| Proto | Local Address | Foreign Address | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | 000.000.00 | laravelproject:0000 | ESTABLISHED |

there are like 10 operations equal like this but with different addresses. 
I'm unsure why these connections are persisting and whether they could have any impact on my system's performance or security. I'm considering terminating them using the kill command, but I want to ensure it's safe to do so.

Can anyone shed some light on why these connections are still appearing and whether terminating them could cause any issues? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That connection is marked as established. I would try to see the process ID (PID) running and kill it to free up some memory. Shouldn't have much impact IMO